# Card Game with WCF and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, workflow-foundation, playing-cards

I started to develop a card game and I'm using WPF for UI and I want to use WCF for communication between clients et server,knowing that I want to put the client and the server on the same application so everyone can be a server, what advise can you give me ?

*WCF is the best way to implement the communication ? or should I use sockets ?

*should I use WF for game logic ?

*if I use WCF, would you advise me to use p2p ?

any advise is welcome and I hope that the idea was clear enough.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008527/silverlightcard-game-and-wcf-communication-with-iis

Comment: This question is too open-ended for stackoverflow. Please see the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask. Do you have *specific requirements* that your game must meet that will help you decide on a technology?

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield, thanks for your attention, my question was just about help for design and choosing a technology.

Answer (score 1):

*WCF is the best way to implement the communication ? or should I use sockets ?
WCF is a good way to implement communication in .NET, sockets would be harder for you.

*should I use WF for game logic ?
never used it.

*if I use WCF, would you advise me to use p2p ?
if it's on the same computer you should use p2p

Comment: thanks for your help, pending further advice, I'll dive into WF to better understand it and I will use tcp for WCF. ( I admit I'm 2.0 and I'm new in 3.5 )